# How to do alternative binding with ControlTemplate in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, binding, templatebinding

I am using `ControlTemplate` have consistent Navigation Bar accross Android and iOS

```xml
<ControlTemplate x:Key="NavBarTemplate">
    <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" 
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
            IsVisible="{TemplateBinding BindingContext.IsBackButtonVisible, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <Label Text="&lt;" 
                FontSize="Large" 
                FontAttributes="Bold" 
                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
                Margin="20,0,0,0" />
            <Label TextColor="{StaticResource DarkGrey}" 
                HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
                FontSize="Small" 
                Text="Back" />
            <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{TemplateBinding BindingContext.NavigateBackCommand}" />
            </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
        </StackLayout>
        <Image Source="logo.png" 
            VerticalOptions="Center" />
    </StackLayout>
</ControlTemplate>
```

In order to dynamically display back button I have added below code in `OnAppearing` of `BasePage.cs`

```cs
protected override void OnAppearing () 
{
    base.OnAppearing ();

    if (BindingContext is BaseViewModel viewmodel) 
    {
        if(Application.Current.MainPage as NavigationPage nav)
        {

            if(nav.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count >1 )
            {
                viewmodel.IsBackButtonVisible = true;
            }else
            {
                viewmodel.IsBackButtonVisible = false;
            }
            //dirty coding force to false
            if (!this.IsBackButtonVisible) //refers to local BindableProperty
            {
                viewmodel.IsBackButtonVisible = false;
            }
        }else //no viewmodel found just use localbinding 
        {
            BindingContext = this;
        }
    }
}
```

So in some pages I want to enforce Back button off even though `NavigationStack` is > `1`

Right now I am achieving based on Dirty coding above by having `BindableProperty` in the BasePage with same name `IsBackButtonVisible`

My question is , is there a way to do alternative binding for `ControlTemplate` , I know there is FallBackValue and Default for normal Binding( which are just values not binding ofcourse) but I dont want to hard code it and seems TemplateBinding doesnt support those(intellisence wont show these options)

What I want to do is rename `BindableProperty` in `BasePage` to `ForceNoBackButton` and make navigation bar invisible despite of ViewModel binding.

Is there any way to do alternative binding in `TemplateBinding` based on conditions..

1. If BindingContext is type of BaseViewModel then use Property `IsBackButtonVisible`
2. Else if page `BindingContext` is this page or something other than `BaseViewModel` then fallback to `BasePage` local `BindableProperty` i.e `ForceNoBackButton`
3. Can I do it with propertychanged event handler of BindableProperty ? If yes, how. I know how to do it if the visual element is in the current XAML, dont know how to do it for `TemplatedView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two bindable properties `IsBackButtonVisible` and `ForceNoBackButton` on `BasePage`.

```
public static readonly BindableProperty ForceNoBackButtonProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create(
    "ForceNoBackButton", typeof(bool), typeof(BasePage),
    defaultValue: default(bool));

public static readonly BindableProperty IsBackButtonVisibleProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create(
    "IsBackButtonVisible", typeof(bool), typeof(BasePage),
    defaultValue: default(bool));
```

And update your control-template to simply use `IsBackButtonVisible`

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="NavBarTemplate">
    ...
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" 
        ..
        IsVisible="{TemplateBinding IsBackButtonVisible}">
```

while modifying `OnAppearing()` method as follows:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    ..
    if (nav.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count > 1)
    {
        IsBackButtonVisible = !ForceNoBackButton;
    }
    else
    {
        IsBackButtonVisible = false;
    }
```

To keep the associated viewmodel in sync with this property - you can either set binding on `BasePage.xaml`, **or** add following line in `BasePage()` constructor to set this binding programmatically.

```
public BasePage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    SetBinding(IsBackButtonVisibleProperty,
         new Binding(nameof(BaseViewModel.IsBackButtonVisible), 
              mode: BindingMode.OneWayToSource));
}
```

Would also recommend to have a property-changed handler for  `ForceNoBackButton` - so you can handle changes to it's value (if they happen after the page has already loaded).