# Disable the back button in navigation bar

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to get rid of only the arrow in the navigation bar in Xamarin forms. I tried in but I didn't get a proper solution. please help me overcome this issue. Thanks in advance.
!! I NEED TO REMOVE PERMANENTLY

solutions that I'm tried up to now :

```
Shell.SetBackButtonBehavior(this, new BackButtonBehavior
        {
           IsEnabled=false
        });
```

but still, this didn't help me

[image]

Comment: https://medium.com/@prateekrm/custom-navigation-bar-with-controltemplate-in-xamarin-forms-7f61e05ebc14

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60780869/how-to-do-alternative-binding-with-controltemplate-in-xamarin-forms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a easy workaround to solve this.

You could override a Icon with a transparent png file(Follow is a transparent png):

[image]

and set `enabled` be `false` as follows:

```
Shell.SetBackButtonBehavior(this, new BackButtonBehavior
{
    IconOverride = "transparent.png",
    IsEnabled = false
}) ;
```

Then the effect as follows:

[image]

Note: You will see that we also can tap that area, therefore we need to set `enabled` be `false`.

Based on [this official sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-xaminals/) to test that.

Answer (score 0):

You can set this using the **Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage** class, from within a view's code behind file.  E.g. within a ContentPage's constructor.

```
NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);
```